# vi.recover/update command appears every minute in cron log. (POSSIBLE VIRUS)

Tags: linux, logging, cron, malware

**UPDATE (7th Dec 2010) & WARNING:** I copied the files discussed below (from the `/var/tmp/vi.recover` directory) to my Windows PC and sacnned with ESET NOD 32. It identifed two of the file (sshd: and juno) as the Linux/RST.B virus. Not sure if it is accurate in saying that but since the machine is a development server I'm going to re-build to be safe.

Hi,

I am getting the following in my cron log file (/var/log/cron) every minute...

```
Dec  2 12:23:01 ocalhost CROND[3189]: (apache) CMD (/var/tmp/vi.recover/update >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec  2 12:24:01 ocalhost CROND[3200]: (apache) CMD (/var/tmp/vi.recover/update >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec  2 12:25:01 ocalhost CROND[3210]: (apache) CMD (/var/tmp/vi.recover/update >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec  2 12:26:01 ocalhost CROND[3218]: (apache) CMD (/var/tmp/vi.recover/update >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Can anyone explain what they are?

I asume they are to do with recovering edits when Vi sessions are aborted. But, I don't understand why they are triggering every minute.

I also cannot find where this command appears in any of my cron files so cannot disable it.

Comment: Is this Linux (if so which distro) or some other OS?

Comment: Sorry, yes, this is on Red Hat Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same thing.  If you have root access, go to `/var/spool/cron` and check the files there.  You'll probably find something like:

```
* * * * * /var/tmp/vi.recover/update >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In my case, it's in Apache's cron file.  My symptom is that every time it runs, it spawns a sshd: process.

Comment: Thanks alot! Yes mine spawns an sshd process each time to which I think is making my slab and buffer memory gradually creep up until it crashes the computer. I'm going to stop the blighter and see what happens.

Comment: If I had enough reputation I would have 'voted you up', I've been looking for that for ages.

Comment: The weird thing is for me that the sshd process it spawns is actually called sshd: and is located in the /var/tmp/vi.recover directory. I think it's not the proper sshd executable. I don't know how it got there but surely sshd has nothing to do with Vi's temorary recovery files. It's slightly worrying as there's other stuff in /var/tmp/vi.recover as well such as one called 'stealth' and 'juno' and 'kswap'. It's a development server so might rebuild.

Comment: If anyone reads this later. My problem was a cron job for the 'apache' user. As root user I did a 'sudo -u apache contab -e' and removed the job that looked like this: * * * * * /var/tmp/vi.recover/update >/dev/null 2>&1. I then rebooted and so far so good. I don't know what the cron job was for or how it got there.

Comment: Robert, if you see this please see my edit right at the top of my original question. I'm being told by my AV that I may have a virus so I would check for this on your machine as well.